# Crash when pushing viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, push

I am trying to pass a variable to another view controller, and I did it accordingly to another tutorial here on the site.
Problem is though, that the segue doesn't seem to work.
noteText, timeline, and timestamp are labels in `EditController` (the controller I'm sending to).

```
- (void)editNoteAction{
    EditNoteController *editNoteController = [[EditNoteController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditNoteController" bundle:nil];
    editNoteController.noteText.text = textString;
    editNoteController.timeline.text = famString;
    editNoteController.timestamp.text = dateString;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:editNoteController animated:YES];
}
```

The original way said I should only use self as sender. That gave me a red warning. After that i've tried `(id)self` and `self.navigationController` but even if none of those left a warning, the program crashed.

Do you have any ideas of what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance,  Tom

Comment: First of all try to run the app without sending values to other controller.. if it runs fine then one bye one send the value to other controller and check in which case app is crashing..

Comment: which type of class is `self` at the moment - a controller?

Comment: It doesn't work without variables either.

Yes, it's a controller.

I get different ones for the examples. Just self wont compile, but i get the warning "No visible @interface for 'MaiNoteController. declares the sector 'pushViewController:animated'. 

self.navigationController gives:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Johanbeijar/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/92EA5F12-1667-4A0C-9B3C-68DAF340BD60/Famorable.app> (loaded)' with name 'EditNoteController''

Answer (score -1):

```
   - (void)editNoteAction
   {
    EditNoteController *editNoteController = [[EditNoteController alloc]initWithNibName:@"EditNoteController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:editNoteController animated:YES];

   }
```

Comment: I am trying to debug the issue, so that it make clear whereas the issue

Comment: do you have a device connected to stackoverflow.com to show the debug result of your code you posted here..??

Comment: I have not connected device, though I am suggesting to the owner of the post to follow..

Comment: ok.. As per error log posted by you: NIB is not loaded so do one thing, Delete old NIB (EditNoteController) and create a new NIB named "EditNoteController" then try.

Comment: Im sorry, how do you delete and create nibs?

Comment: Oh..no issue. if r not able to delete or re create new NIB.

Comment: could you please create a new Viewcontroller(.h,.m and xib) and give it a different name assume TestVw. Now push to this viewcontroller, let me know is this working now..

Comment: in this new controller xib, just put a simple label and set its text as  "Hello test". If this view controller works fine then copy/paste ur code of EditNotecontroller to this viewcontroller

Comment: Nope: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Johanbeijar/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/92EA5F12-1667-4A0C-9B3C-68DAF340BD60/Famorable.app> (loaded)' with name 'TestViewController''... 

When I try (id)self I get: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainNoteController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6ab0ce0'

Comment: I figured a modal segue worked, and since it's the last controller in the branch it's not too big of a deal.

Thanks @iOS Test for your effort :)